# Error:(36, 74) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to Context

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment called CalendarFragment. I am getting this error when i tried executing the program.
Error:(36, 74) error: incompatible types: CalendarFragment cannot be converted to Context

CalendarFragment :

```
package app.pal.study.samplestudy;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CalendarFragment  extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calendar);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refresh();
}

private void refresh() {
    CalendarEventDataSource dataSource = new CalendarEventDataSource(this);
    dataSource.openReadOnlyDB();
    final List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents = dataSource.getAllEvents();
    dataSource.close();

    CalAllEventsListAdapter adapter = new CalAllEventsListAdapter(calendarEvents);

    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.all_event_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        end();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    end();
}

private void end() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(Constants.DATE_KEY, (Date) getIntent().getExtras().get(Constants.DATE_KEY));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: remove setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calendar); and call getActivity() where you need Context...!!

Comment: Please Learn about Fragment first than ask question if you get any problem. There are many example how you set view in Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity.

1. Call `onCreateView` instead of `onCreate`. Remove `onCreate()`
2. call **getActivity()** instead of **<s>this</s>**. **getActivity() Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with**.

> CalendarEventDataSource dataSource = new
>   CalendarEventDataSource(getActivity());

Problem

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calendar);
}
```

This code for Activity . You should use your `onCreateView` method .

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
        return rootView;
  }
```

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: +One,  Not at all, You made me learn "Either don't write answer Or just write it the best way"

Answer (score 3):

remove `setcontentview` from `onCreate` method you already set view in `onCreateView`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your error is indicating the line `CalendarEventDataSource dataSource = new CalendarEventDataSource(this);`

Try and change `this` with either `getActivity()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` or `getActivity().getBaseContext()`.

Also no need for `onCreate()` as other have suggested.

Comment: Please see his question, setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calendar); in onCreate , How we setContentView in onCreate method of fragment.

Comment: Asking me to see the question really? @Jack what you see wrong in Question or my answer here? onCreateView is all fine, just need to remove onCreate, what you are thinking?

Comment: i am not able to get  setContentView in onCreate if you are i don't know...but this PersianBlue didn't know about fragment. you have to suggest him to learn about fragment before asking question.

Comment: @MKJParekh Sir `getApplicationContext()` Not applicable here .Its fragment

Comment: I meant `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` , sorry for poor writings .! anyways, updated. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @Jack OMG.! If I will make mistake in saying About me, you will tell me to go and learn about my self, There may be typing mistakes, copy paste mistakes, We just need to see the problem and again you should see that **I am telling to remove onCreate() in my answer, I dont know what you are reading out of it**